# Check to update and then insert multiple records at once in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have 2 tables relating to a survey. When user answers each set of questions and then click the submit button, it will loop each answer according to the form submitted in order to check within the database first, if the CustomerID and QuestionID have been found, then do the Update. If not found, do the Insert instead.

**QUESTIONS** table

- QuestionID (PK)
- QuestionText

**ANSWERS** table

- AnswerID (PK)
- CustomerID (FK)
- QuestionID (FK)
- AnswerText

  ```
  <html>
  ....
  <form action="/db.php" method="POST">
   <?php echo $questiontext[1]; ?><input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1">
   <?php echo $questiontext[2]; ?><input type="text" name="answer2" id="answer2">
   <?php echo $questiontext[3]; ?><input type="text" name="answer3" id="answer3">
   <?php echo $questiontext[4]; ?><input type="text" name="answer4" id="answer4">
   <?php echo $questiontext[5]; ?><input type="text" name="answer5" id="answer5">
   <?php echo $questiontext[6]; ?><input type="text" name="answer6" id="answer6">

   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  ...
  </html>
  ```

---

**db.php**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $cusid = intval($_POST['CustomerID']);
      $answer1 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer1']);
      $answer2 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer2']);
      $answer3 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer3']);
      $answer4 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer4']);
      $answer5 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer5']);
      $answer6 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer6']);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO Answers (CustomerID, QuestionID, AnswerText) VALUES     
      ('".$cusid."','".$quesid."','".$answer."')";
      $res = $db->query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
    }
    ?>
```

My questions are:

1. How to update each answer(1-6) one by one and then insert into the database if CustomerID and QuestionID have not been found by using array and SQL query, if found, then just update?
2. How could I reference the QuestionID in order to related with AnswerText in HTML and PHP?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider what happens if someone sets their answer to `answer'); DROP TABLE Answers'`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Is it better with $db->real_escape_string?

Comment: Assuming `$db` is something like an instance of `mysqli`, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea for you. Hope you can understand it. Make sure you replace database driven functions with your `$db` object.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT QuestionID FROM Questions ORDER BY QuestionID ";
    $res = $db->query($sql);
    $qus = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    {
        $questionID = $row['QuestionID'] ;
        $answer = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['answer' . $qus ]);


        $sql = "SELECT AnswerID  FROM Answers WHERE CustomerID='$cusid' AND QuestionID='$questionID' ";
        $resAns = $db->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $resAns->num_rows; // This should be replace with your $db object record count obtaining method
        if($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE Answers SET AnswerText = '$answer' WHERE CustomerID='$cusid' AND QuestionID='$questionID'  ";
            // Execute your update query
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Answers (CustomerID, QuestionID, AnswerText) VALUES     
  ('".$cusid."','".$questionID."','".$answer."')";
            // Execute your insert statement
        }
        $qus ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got these following errors:
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
By the way, how to update and insert only the answer which isn't null.

Comment: It's depending on the library you are using. 1. mysql 2.mysqli 3. PDO

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this >> 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

Comment: Solved! Only use the different variable to keep the query result, use $result to keep QuestionID (Question table) and use $res to update/insert data. The rest of them, your code is perfect! My problem has been solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a select query first and then see how many rows have been returned from there something like this

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE CustomerId = '$cusid' OR QuestionId =                '$quesid' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
   if($num_rows == 1)
     {
          // value exists run the update
     }
     else
     { 
           // go ahead with insert query
     }
```

Comment: how to repeatedly loop this process then? And also how and where could I link QuestionID with AnswerText in html and then send it to db.php?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a unique key on CustomerID+QuestionID, then you can just do an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Let the database handle the checks.